# PHPStorm PHPDoc how to declare array parameter that have DateTime object in it?

Tags: php, phpdoc

So, I have some method with a parameter expecting an array. Like this:

```
private function handler($db_data){
    $formatted_date = $db_data['StartDate']->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
}
```

As you can see, this array have DateTime object in it. The problem is that I don't know how to declare this DateTime object using PHPDoc, so PHPStorm is telling me that method 'format' is not found. Anybody know how to solve it? Don't propose to suppress this warning :) Thanks

Answer (score 3):

The only thing I can come up with (since arrays are dynamically typed) is this:

```
/** @var \DateTime $unformatted_date */
$unformatted_date = $db_data['StartDate'];
$formatted_date = $unformatted_date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

**EDIT**

Side note: don't rely too much on your IDE. My answer isn't really useful, since your original statement was perfectly readable and it conveys the meaning well. The phpdoc isn't going to typecheck your array, so it's literally only there to remove the warning your IDE is giving you. It obstructs code readability in my opinion. It's up to you ofcourse, but I would use comments like these for very complicated datastructures. Not for code that is perfectly readable and concise.

Comment: As there are not only `DateTime` Objects, this should be the closest approach possible using PHPDoc

Comment: Thanks. I don't really like to declare new variable only for that purpose, but it's the closest one  :)

Comment: Yeah, that was I was getting at in the side note :)

Answer (score 0):

You could store it in a temporary variable and add PHPDoc there. For instance:

```
/** @var DateTime $date */
$date = $db_data['StartDate'];
```

That way PhpStorm should know the available methods.

Comment: So you pass a DateTime object, access that as array and then format on that element? Something doesn't seem right ;)

Comment: You are right, I missread the question. I will edit my answer as soon as I found out how